# How to get full month name with DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()

Tags: java, date-formatting, java-time, datetimeformatter

When I use this code to get the actual date:

```
String dateActuelle = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM uuuu").format(LocalDate.now());
```

It returns "**06 sept. 2021**" in french but I would like to get "**06 septembre 2021**" (full month name).

Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: It's printing full september for me. Even it is expected to print full as you have used 4 characters for month. My result : 06 September 2021

Comment: Well I guess I got a confusion somewhere, thanks for confirming my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `MMMM` it will give the full month name, like September
while, `MMM` will give month name in short, like Sept

Please verify by mistake you might have typed 3 M's while formatting in code.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `MMMM` does not appear to work when you specify `Locale.ROOT` (I got a 3-letter abbreviation for the month name in English). You need either use the default system locale or specific a language using something like `Locale.ENGLISH`.